# pass default value from graphql query in apollo to child

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I am trying to pass graphql query value to my React component from the parent component's state. My method isn't work working because it's loading and isn't called again after it is done loading. Any recommendations on how to do this?

```
class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     const defaultSelectedId = (this.props.query && !this.props.query.loading) ? 
           this.props.query.defaultId : ''
     this.state = { 
         id: defaultSelectedId
     }
   render() {
      return(
<Child selectedId={this.state.id} />
)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
const defaultSelectedId = (nextProps.query && !nextProps.query.loading) ? 
           nextProps.query.defaultId : ''
     this.setState ({ 
         id: defaultSelectedId
     })

}
```

Comment: You can also remove that from the constructor. Initialization only happens once and it will be `loading = true` when it does.

Comment: Also add a check to see if it actually changed. `(nextProps.query && !nextProps.query.loading && nextProps.query.defaultId !== this.state.id)`.
P.S. unless you're handling the empty string `id` in your Child component, or your render is more complex than what you're showing, you should prevent rendering it while loading is true.

Comment: Thank you both, this was very helpful and it is now working. Although this.setState =... should be this.setState(...